# Convert string to appropriate date with timezone java

Tags: java, date, timezone

I am Having Date with it's timezone, I want to convert it to another Timezone, E.g. I have Date '3/15/2013 3:01:53 PM' which is in TimeZone 'GMT-06:00'. I want to convert this in 'GMT-05:00' timezone. I have search lot, and I am confuse about How actually Date is working. How to Apply timezone to date. I have try with SimpleDateFormat, Calender and also with offset.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa XXX");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); 
Date dt = null;
try {
    dt = df.parse("3/15/2013 3:01:53 PM -06:00");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
String newDateString = df.format(dt);
System.out.println(newDateString);
```

It returns output 
`03/15/2013 09:01:53 AM Z`.
I guess it should be 
`03/15/2013 09:01:53 PM Z`, because time in 'GMT-06:00' timezone, so it should be HH+6 to get time in GMT. I want Date in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format where HH is in 24 hour.Please Help me with example. Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

I am converting the string into date using SimpleDateFormat

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa");
    Date dt = null;
    try {
        dt = df.parse("3/15/2013 3:01:53 PM");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now, as you say, I specify to Calendar that my date is in 'GMT-06:00' timezone and set my date,

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-6"));
cal.setTime(dt);
```

Now, I am telling calendar that I want date in 'GMT'

```
cal.setTimeZone (TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

System.out.println(cal.getTime());

OutPut:

```
Fri Mar 15 03:01:53 CDT 2013
```

Please know me if i am going wrong.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need TWO format objects, one for parsing and another one for printing because you use two different timezones, see here:

```
// h instead of H  because of AM/PM-format
DateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aaa XXX"); 
Date dt = null;
try {
  dt = parseFormat.parse("3/15/2013 3:01:53 PM -06:00");
}catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} 

DateFormat printFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aaa XXX"); 
printFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-05")); 
String newDateString = printFormat.format(dt);
System.out.println(newDateString);
```

Output: 3/15/2013 04:01:53 PM -05:00

If you want HH:mm:ss (24-hour-format) then you just replace

```
hh:mm:ss aaa
```

by

```
HH:mm:ss
```

in printFormat-pattern.

---

Comment on other aspects of question:

A `java.util.Date` has no internal timezone and always refers to UTC by spec. You cannot change it inside this object. A timezone conversion is possible for the formatted string, however as demonstrated in my code example (you wanted to convert to zone GMT-05).

The question then switches to the new requirement to print the `Date`-object in ISO-format using UTC timezone (symbol Z). This can be done in formatting by replacing the pattern with "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX" and explicitly setting the timezone of printFormat to GMT+00. You should clarify what you really want as formatted output.

About `java.util.GregorianCalendar`: Setting the timezone here is changing the calendar-object in a programmatical way, so it affects method calls like `calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)`. This has nothing to do with formatting however!

Comment: now, what if I want Date object from string, when i print Date object after parsing it display my local timezone and datetime

Comment: @minu `Date` from `String` = use parsing format, printing `Date` = setting the timezone on printFormat (for local timezone use `TimeZone.getDefault()`) and define patterns (you should also avoid to use `Date.toString()` because latter one just uses a predefined format based on system timezone - only useful for debugging if at all).

Comment: I used parse of SimpleDateFormat to get Date Object          `String newDateString = printFormat.format(dt);
try {
  dt = printFormat.parse(newDateString); 
}catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(dt);`                                             It display Local time, also I just return dt and trying to store in database it display time '00:00:00'

Comment: @minu `System.out.println(dt)` uses `Date.toString()`. Avoid it please. Instead use a dedicated print format and specify pattern, locale and timezone on that to get the output you wish. About time 00:00:00: Probably you have a SQL-DATE-column in db which nullifies time part - see also the adapter jdbc class `java.sql.Date`. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( 
    "3/15/2013 3:01:53 PM -06:00" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss a XXX" )
).withOffsetSameInstant( 
    ZoneOffset.of( -5 , 0 ) 
)
```

> 2013-03-15T15:01:53-06:00

## java.time

The [Answer by Hochschild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23673926/642706) is correct but uses outdated classes. The troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java have been supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes.

Parse your input string as a `OffsetDateTime` as it contains an offset-from-UTC but not a time zone.

```
String input = "3/15/2013 3:01:53 PM -06:00";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a XXX" );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> odt.toString(): 2013-03-15T15:01:53-06:00

Tip: Save yourself some hassle and use the ISO 8601 formats when exchanging date-time data as text. The java.time classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

Apparently you want to see the same moment as viewed by the people elsewhere using a different offset-from-UTC.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of( -5 , 0 ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt2 = odt.withOffsetSameInstant( offset ) ;
```

We see the offset changes from 6 to 5, and the hour-of-day changes accordingly from 15 to 16. Same simultaneous moment, different wall-clock time.

> odt2.toString(): 2013-03-15T16:01:53-05:00

## Generating strings

> I want Date in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format where HH is in 24 hour.

I suggest you always include some indication of the offset or zoneunless your are absolutely certain the user understands from the greater context.

Your format is nearly in standard ISO 8601 format. You could define your own formatting pattern, but I would just do string manipulation to replace the `T` in the middle with a SPACE.

```
String output = odt2.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ).replace( "T" , " " ) ;
```

> 2013-03-15 16:01:53

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

With a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complying with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings or java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).